# Movimiento constante de un actor en libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Estoy desarrollando un juego en `libgdx`.

El juego consta de un actor, el cual la cámara sigue constantemente con dicho actor centrado.

Mi problema es que no se resolver el movimiento del actor, pues me gustaría que tubiera un comportamiento como `Snake.io`, la serpiente siempre se mueve y sólo le añades/cambias la dirección.

De momento no muevo el actor porque quería averiguar como hacer el movimiento que he preguntado. De todas maneras el movimiento que usaría es un movimiento simple:

```
public static final float SPEED = 100;
....
@Override
public void render(float delta){
   ....
   actor.setPosition(actor.getX() + (SPEED * delta * dirX), actor.getY() + (SPEED * delta * dirY));
   ....
}
```

dirX y dirY son las coordenadas del joystic para optener la direccion.

Es un juego en 2D y con vista cenital. Me gustaría que siempre se mueva, hacia delante. Hacia delante me refiero a se si gira el actor, siga yendo hacia delante, manteniendo la dirección que ha tomado el actor. Dicha dirección la obtengo con el joystick.

translate no me funciona, es más no me aparece la opción. Igual es porque no uso sprites, uso texturas y actores. Además, Estoy usando Scene2D y box2D, que no lo había mencionado antes.

Necesito crear un movimiento del actor continuo, que sin que el usuario pusle ningún botón, se mueva, pero que cuando el usuario mueva el joystick se le aplique esa dirección al actor, el actor puede moverse libremente por toda la pantalla

Comment: Hola Oliva, bienvenida. Deberias añadir algo de codigo que tengas para contextualizarnos. Por ejemplo el codigo que usas para mover al actor. Un saludo

Comment: ¿No falta la etiqueta de Java?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien su pregunta. dices que se mueva yo entiendo que quieres que este siempre en movimiento, podrias aclarar un poco, por ejemplo es un juego tipo plataformas, hacia donde quieres que se mueva siempre? y/o cuando quieres que cambie ect. Hace años que no uso LibGDX pero igual te puedo ayudar yo u otro usuario. Aparte y aunque en este caso no sea muy relevante, yo te recomiendo que uses translate ->  https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#translate-float-float-

Comment: aunque setPosition hace uso de transtale creo que es mejor usar translate aparte de ser mas entendible, igual si usas fisica en algun momento te lias. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.java#L187 Saludos

Comment: Quizas no me explique bien, cual es es determinate que dice la direccion que tiene el actor, un ejemplo seria el actor siempre se mueve, pero la direccion es determinada por hacia donde este mirando, si mira para la derecha (desde el punto de vista del jugador) se mueve por ejemplo 10 unidades en el eje de las x hasta que mire para otro lado (asumo que es un juego en 2D, tambien dependera de la matrix de projeccion de la camara ect), pero para no liarnos creo que se entiende.Podrias editar tu pregunta con un ejemplo de como quieres que se comporte tu actor. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel El jugador se puede mover por toda la pantalla, usando la **X** y/o la **Y**. Es un juego en 2D y con vista cenital. Me gustaría que siempre se mueva, hacia delante. Hacia delante me refiero a se si gira el actor, siga yendo hacia delante, manteniendo la dirección que ha tomado el actor. La dirección la obtengo con el joystick

Comment: si usted pone por ejemplo `actor.translateX (10);` en el render este se mueve? si no es la direccion que quiere pues translateY o -10 ect. me puede comentar si esto hace que se mueva el actor?. Supongamos que si, despues puede poner otra rutina de movimiento, ej: actor.translate... para que siempre se mueva en esa direccion y actor.translate... si este tambien es controlado por el usuario en ambos ejes y si solo en uno pues el metodo que precise. Saludos

Comment: ¿que es delta?.

Comment: delta es el el tiempo entre frames. Lo uso para que el movimiento de los actores no vaya a trompicones y sea más fluido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de muchas vueltas he encontrado la solución. No es exacta si se usa el joystic pero cumple con lo quie qería. Grácias a todos por vuestra ayuda.

El código del movimiento, dentro del método render()

```
private void move(float delta) {
    if ((dirX == (float) 0.000015258789 && dirY == (float) -0.007827878)) {
        dirX = 0.0f;
        dirY = 0.0f;
    }
    if (!(dirX == 0.0 && dirY == 0.0)) {
        moveAction(delta);
        lastDirX = dirX;
        lastDirY = dirY;
        assigned = false;
    } else {
        if (!assigned) {
            dirX = lastDirX;
            dirY = lastDirY;
            assigned = true;
        }
    }
    getBody().setTransform(
            (getX() * METERS_IN_PIXELS) + (METERS_IN_PIXELS * dirX * (PLAYER_SPEED + speedExtra)),
            (getY() * METERS_IN_PIXELS) + (METERS_IN_PIXELS * dirY * (PLAYER_SPEED + speedExtra)),
            getRotation()
    );

    getScreen().getStage().getCamera().position.x = (getX() + (getWidth() / 2))
            + (METERS_IN_PIXELS * dirX * (PLAYER_SPEED + speedExtra));
    getScreen().getStage().getCamera().position.y = (getY() - (getHeight() * METERS_IN_PIXELS) / 2)
            + (METERS_IN_PIXELS * dirY * (PLAYER_SPEED + speedExtra));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución podría ser guardar la penúltima posición ademas de la última, estos dos datos nos darán la dirección (negativa o positiva) en la que se esta moviendo.

```
if(penultimoX != null && penultimoX != null){
    dirX=actor.getX()-penultimoX;
    dirY=actor.getY()-penultimoY;
}else{
    dirX=1;
    dirY=1;
}
actor.setPosition(actor.getX()+(SPEED*delta*dirX), actor.getY()+(SPEED delta*dirY));
penultimoX=actor.getPositionX;
penultimoY=actor.getPositionY;
```

puedes comentar, el listener que recibe el dato que pulsa el usuario?

Comment: Grácias por la ayuda a todos. @Maguz, no necesito obtener la dirección que va a tomar, igual esque no me he explicado bien, nada raro en mi.

Necesito crear un movimiento del actor continuo, que sin que el usuario pusle ningún botón, se mueva, pero que cuando el usuario mueva el joystick se le aplique esa dirección al actor, el actor puede moverse libremente por toda la pantalla. Grácias